# How to obtain the Originator_Account_Id for transactions more than 100 000 and more than one transaction. without using a having clause?

Tags: sql-server

```
Originator_Acc_ID     |      Transaction_Amount  
-----------------------------------------------
001                   |           10000000 
001                   |           20000000
003                   |               1000 
002                   |           60000000
```

I want the Originator_ID for the transactions above 100 000 only and more than 1 transaction without using a having clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know the `Originator_Acc_ID` with more than one transaction then you could use row_number:

```
select Originator_Acc_ID, Transaction_Amount
from
(
  select Originator_Acc_ID, Transaction_Amount,
    row_number() over(partition by Originator_Acc_ID order by Originator_Acc_ID) rn
  from yourtable
  --where Transaction_Amount > 100000
) src
where rn > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10504/3)

If they have a `row_number()` greater than one it means they have more than one transaction. The above will return all of those with more than one. If you only want a list of the accounts with more than one transaction, then you can use:

```
select distinct Originator_Acc_ID
from
(
  select Originator_Acc_ID, Transaction_Amount,
    row_number() over(partition by Originator_Acc_ID order by Originator_Acc_ID) rn
  from yourtable
  --where Transaction_Amount > 100000
) src
where rn > 1
```

Or even:

```
select Originator_Acc_ID
from
(
  select Originator_Acc_ID, Transaction_Amount,
    row_number() over(partition by Originator_Acc_ID order by Originator_Acc_ID) rn
  from yourtable
  --where Transaction_Amount > 100000
) src
where rn = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but this seems to work;

```
;WITH MyTable AS
(
    SELECT   Originator_Acc_ID  = '001'
            ,Transaction_Amount =  10000000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '001', 20000000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '003', 1000
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '002', 60000000
)
,CTE AS
(
    SELECT   Originator_Acc_ID
            ,Transaction_Amount
            ,TxnPerOrig = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Originator_Acc_ID)

    FROM MyTable
)
SELECT DISTINCT Originator_Acc_ID
FROM CTE
WHERE Transaction_Amount > 100000
AND TxnPerOrig > 1
```